# Why does filament feed system not run when changing filament?

Tags: filament

When changing filament during a print job I get a message to feed new filament, then press Okay. After pressing Okay, I get the message "Please insert the filament" - but nothing happens.

I repeatedly press the Okay, but nothing. I can load filament, but that requires stopping the print job. Seems like a software problem to me. Any advice? No, it's not the nozzle temperature or any such thing. The filament feed system does not run when Okay is pressed.

Comment: Could you please update the question by [edit] to let us know the printer, the firmware and possibly part of the G-code to show the filament change?